# Why does Rust Closure take ownership before being called

Tags: rust, closures

I'm going through the Rust book, and I'm on the chapter describing closures. I'm a bit confused about why the following example errors due to the closure taking ownership:

```
fn main() {
let x = vec![1, 2, 3];

let equal_to_x = move |z| z == x;

println!("can't use x here: {:?}", x);

let y = vec![1, 2, 3];

assert!(equal_to_x(y));
}
```

Namely, why does `equal_to_x` take ownership of `x` before it's even called? Shouldn't the compiler know that the closure hasn't been called (because it is owned by `main`) and thus x can still be owned by the outside scope of `main`?

Comment: why not ? it's more simple, keep the workflow clear. If you want change use x before just create your closure after.

Comment: If you're asking why its not moved lazily, that's not a thing that exists because lifetimes are checked statically. If you're asking why the compiler doesn't reorder your statements so that it works, that's also not a thing that Rust does.

Comment: For me it makes more sense to take the ownership before hand in closure so that if you need to mutate the state of variable in closure itself

Comment: You can pass the closure around before calling it. The closure may even outlive `x`. It's impossible to lazily take ownership once the closure is called for the first time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because a closure is essentially a struct with a function associated with it. I find it easier to think of closures like this:

```
struct MyClosure{
    x: Vec<i32>
};

impl MyClosure {
    pub fn execute(self, z: Vec<i32>) -> bool {
        z == self.x
    }
}
```

If thought of like this, your code is equivalent to

```
let equal_to_x  = MyClosure {
    x
};
```

so you can see why the move has happened.

Comment: Awesome, this makes sense conceptually and is a useful mental model. Thank you!